# JS - Color Picker Only first one works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, color-picker

I am using [Bootstrap Colorpicker 2.1](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?zETM2MpT) in order to display two colour pickers in a form.
Everything works fine using one input however, when I add the second one only the first one is working. Maybe because they are sharing the same class…

Any Idea why is this happening?

```
<form method="post">

<p><?php _e("Box 1: " ); ?>
<input 
class="form-control demo" 
data-horizontal="true" 
id="demo_forceformat" 
placeholder="<?php echo $box1?>" 
type="text" 
name="box1" 
value="<?php echo $box1?>" 
size="20">
<?php _e(" Default: rgba(14,112,209,1)" ); ?></p>

<p><?php _e("Box 2 " ); ?>
<input 
class="form-control demo" 
data-horizontal="true" 
id="demo_forceformat" 
placeholder="<?php echo $box2?>" 
type="text" 
name="box2" 
value="<?php echo $box2?>" 
size="20">
<?php _e(" Default: rgba(144,112,209,1)" ); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to call the function using

```
$(function(){
    $('#demo_forceformat_2').colorpicker({
            format: 'rgba', // force this format
            horizontal: true
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it could be related to sharing the same id.

ids should be unique for each element on the page.

change `id="demo_forceformat"` to `id="demo_forceformat2"`, or even better, have the same values for the id property as the name property.  It is a common convention to use the same id and name values for form elements.

Comment: Thank you Allan, I think this is the issue however, If I change to id="demo_forceformat2" still does not work as javascript don't know the new value

Comment: can't really help more without seeing a working example. jsfiddle or codepen.  Your javascript selector might not be capturing all of the inputs when executing the .colorpicker() method.